# "Number of Keys" is missing from "nodetool cfstats" output in cassandra 2.1.2. How to get the count of rows now?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, database, nosql

I badly need the count of rows in a ColumnFamily but "Number of Keys" is missing from "nodetool cfstats" output in cassandra 2.1.2. How to get the count of rows now?

Here is the output of cfstats

```
Keyspace: liftrmt
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms.
    Write Count: 0
    Write Latency: NaN ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: reportcodedaycount
            SSTable count: 4
            Space used (live): 11.49 MB
            Space used (total): 11.49 MB
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0 bytes
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.38099920748493266
            Memtable cell count: 0
            Memtable data size: 0 bytes
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 0
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 0
            Local write latency: NaN ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 64 bytes
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 444.17 KB
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 6.68 MB
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 4.17 MB
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the new metrics that can be accessed via JMX. I'll access them using JConsole.

Open up jconsole then navigate to:

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics
    -> ColumnFamily
        -> ksname (in my case test)
            -> cfname (in my case group)
                -> EstimatedColumnCountHistogram
                    -> Attributes -> Value
```

Open up the long [90] array, and in my case it's the second value. These are keys that are in sstables, if it's in a memtable, it wont be accessable through this metric (i.e. if you wanna see it, you need to flush your memtables to sstables).

Screenshot of 22 unique keys inserted into **test.group** below for clarity...

[image: JConsole showing 22 inserted keys into cassandra]

More on the [new metrics API](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2).

Comment: Just an info...if someone does not have x-server(GUI) to run JConsole, then he can use jmxterm from the command line itself

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** This issue is now solved in 2.1.3.

I went ahead and created a jira for this. Not sure why number of keys is missing in 2.1.2:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8400